# How to close one explorer.exe's window instead of ending the whole process

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, freeze, threads

I use MTP to transfer photos from my Android to my PC and then the whole explorer.exe gets stuck in a waiting loop and I can't close that one window except by terminating the process and losing the newly arranged icons on desktop and all open windows. Is there an alternative explorer.exe like ReactOS version or a way to close just one window or a script that terminates just that one single stupid thread that is broken?

Comment: If you cannot end the process on the single window, then what you want to do, can only be accomplished by restarting the windows explorer process.

Comment: Is it possible to make all windows have each-for-each process like modern web browsers where if one process dies, not all of them do?

Comment: Killing explorer will only close open explorer window **not** all windows.

Comment: @Foxcat385 - Windows Explorer is not a browser, while it can be modified in certain ways, changing how it actually treats a thread is outside of the scope of a hack.  Which means your limited to using a entirely different shell if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate the option to [run Windows Explorer Folders In A Separate Process](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/run-windows-explorer-folders-in-a-separate-process-to-prevent-crashes-and-system-freeze/). Open the Folder Options in Windows Explorer and select the setting and reboot.

[image]

Now the File Explorer runs separated from the shell and closing a stuck Explorer Window won't kill the shell.